Other idiomatic phrases conveying the same meaning as "pulling rank"?
During my time abroad, I came across a phrase pulling rank, I found the phrase really fascinating, and I noticed that with dogs as well (this is my interpretation, I could be wrong) i.e. there are ranks among dogs and they pull rank on one another.
In India, we have competitive exams where we are given ranks unlike global exams like GRE, SAT where there is %ile unlike ranks. So, in India, we can pull rank on one another.
Are there other idiomatic phrase which convey the same meaning as pulling rank?

The term refers to taking unfair advantage of one's high rank in an organisation. I'm not sure how this would relate to marks in an exam.

@KateBunting Is it always "unfair"? I mean is it always used in negative context?

Many dictionaries mention unfairness in their definitions.

The point of the expression is that the person is using their high rank inappropriately. If a colonel gives orders to a captain during a military campaign, that isn't pulling rank, it's just doing his job.

@KateBunting regarding your exam/marks comment, why can't somebody pull his rank? A person with better rank can always cite his superior rank to claim superiority?

I don't know how the Indian system works, but if getting high marks gives someone a status that they can use to obtain privileges that are not a normal part of their job, you could call that 'pulling rank'.

@KateBunting Let's say two guys appear in an exam and get respective ranks. Later, in an argument, one can pull his rank to claim victory in the argument?

No, that's not how it works. Rank in this context refers to a senior job in an organisation. Such people have certain privileges as part of their job, but pulling rank would be using their high status to get extra privileges not related to the job.

Collins Dictionary defines to pull rank:

If you say that someone in authority pulls rank, you mean that they unfairly force other people to do what they want because of their higher rank or position.

We could consider throwing one's weight around and bossing around.
I’m not sure whether these phrases apply to dogs but won’t be surprised if they do to such intelligent animals.
